# RazorEngine (outside MVC) - Possible to register templates without explicitly specifying the model type?

Tags: .net, razor

Is it possible to register templates without specifying the model type?

Currently it works like so (taken from: [documentation](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Quick%20Start%20Guide&referringTitle=Documentation)):

```
//Code to get template string from file xxx.cshtml into template variable
Razor.Compile(template, typeof(SomeModel), "complex");
```

However I would like to precompile the templates taking the model type definition from the `@model` or `@inherits` directive in the view. Is this possible?

Comment: Hmm, good question - what if you change typeof(SomeModel) to dynamic ?

Comment: Does `CompileWithAnonymous` help?

Comment: @Russ: There is no `typeof(dynamic)`.  It's just `object`.

Comment: Indeed, I meant replacing the typeof part too.

Comment: @SLaks: Good point. I'm being hypothetical here though, I'm using a lightweight engine comprised of several bits of information. I'm thinking about switching to RazorEngine at Codeplex, hence the question. I'm gonna prepare a solution to test it out.

Comment: @Russ C: Another good point. I'm not into `dynamic` types, I know they are used in Razor, I have no idea on how they work yet though.

Comment: `dynamic` types are not used in Razor.  However, the standard base class (`WebPageBase`) has a couple of dynamic properties.  You only need `dynamic` if you want weak typing.

Comment: I'll be interested to see how you get along, I'm hoping to use Razor templating in an up-coming development.

Comment: @Russ C: I'm currently implementing it in a Webforms CMS. It all works and is able to replace user controls nicely. However it needs some shaving here and there before I'll release it as an open-source module. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @SLaks, Ok, not the Razor markup itself but it's misleading to say it's not used; ViewBag is used a lot and is dynamic.

Comment: @Russ: The module is done. Don't know if you're using Sitecore but here it is: http://dotnetminute.blogspot.com/2011/06/razorforsitecore-module-enable-razor.html

Comment: Cool, I'll have a look when I've stopped being code monkey :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Razor.Compile` doesn't require a model type to be specified when compiled.

```
public class ActualType { public string Firstname {get;set;}}

Razor.Compile("@Model.Firstname", "outputname");
Razor.Run<ActualType>(model, "outputname");
```

Should run for you just fine.

The `@model` declaration isn't available yet. Currently there's a patch for it on the list of patches page ( http://razorengine.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/patches ), however it only adds design time support and not runtime. The current reason for this is because the MVC RazorEngine already does this and we didn't want confusion as to whether this razor engine is the same as the MVC razor implementation (a lot of people think that)

We're looking at implementing it for v2.2 when we both have time to work on it.

As long as the model you pass in matches the required parameters in use by the template you might be good to go.

It actually shouldn't be too difficult to modify the patch to force the template to use the `@model` declaration as it's `template<t>`. I could work on it tonight possibly if it's a serious requirement. I'm curious as to why you don't want to include it in the compilation declaration unless you're worried about changing models or you don't know the model beforehand...but in the end you always know the type before you pass it in.

Comment: Finally got it running! "Unable to cast object of type 'RazorEngine.Compilation.RazorDynamicObject' to type 'SomeSpace.SomeModel'." is thrown if I specify `@inherits` directive. If I omit the declaration it runs fine! However `@inherits` or `@model` are required for Visual Studio to have intellisense support...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source, yes.

The `modelType` parameter specifies a *default* type, and itself defaults to `dynamic` if omitted.

However, if the view explicitly specifies its base type, that should override it.

Note that I haven't tried it; I'm just deducing from the source.

Comment: I don't want a non-generic template. The thing is, I don't want to specify the model type twice. It's already defined (as string) at the top of the template, why bother specifying it again when calling the compile function?

Comment: @Ropstah: I'm not sure.  Read through the source or try it yourself; I may be wrong.  (I haven't used RazorEngine yet)

Comment: Looking at it further, it looks like the `ModelType` parameter just specifies a default base type, and that you'll still get a generic type if the view says so.